# Is there a way to 'refresh' a Google Drive file watcher?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

The situation is that we'll have a nested directory structure shared out selectively to many users, thousands of watchers with each watcher being responsible for dozens of files and updating easily 20+ users.

I've gathered that the cap on watcher duration is ~42 days before it has to be re-created.

What I'd love to see is something like `rewatch( fileId, channel )` or `channel.refresh(duration)`. Is there no way to refresh a watcher without creating a new one and having to deal with either a gap in coverage or an overlap with double-updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push), there is no way to [refresh](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push#renewing-notification-channels) the notification channel. After a channel has expired, a new one has to be created.

It is also mentioned that you can provide an expiration time when creating the notification channel. For Drive, the maximum time is 86400 (1 day) for Files and 604800 (1 week) for Changes.

You maybe reduce the time of gap or overlap keeping track of the expiration time provided but still you will have to deal with it.

Comment: Wow, that short? That's horrible. We have to manually cycle through thousands of watchers every day?

Comment: So, given that (one day, wow), what's the proper way to watch for changes on many thousands of files? Surely it's not intended to have to `watch() / stop()` every file every day? We'd run out of execution seconds after only about 30k files

Comment: Well, the one day is to watch for a specific file. but watching the resource 'changes' would allow you to receive all the modification in Drive.

Comment: So the intended method is to get spammed with notifications on every user's every change, then filter based on the files you actually care about? That seems invasive and awkward. Feels like there should be a way to watch a folder and cascade down to all subfolders. Is there a filter on the 'changes' resource to prevent irrelevant webhooks from even firing?